# If statement within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning, I'm building a website for a client, I'm using Wordpress for the CMS and my PHP knowledge is very limited. I'm using the Custom Fields Plugin and I'm trying to add an if statement within the template to show the meta data if it the field is filled out within the CMS, this is what I have at the moment, but it still shows the button even if the meta field isn't filled out.

```
<?php if(get_field('owners_manual')) ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('owners_manual'); ?>" class="pdf-button" target=_"blank">Owners Manual</a>
<?php }  ?>

<?php if(get_field('parts_booklet')) ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('parts_booklet'); ?>" class="parts-button" target=_"blank">Parts Booklet</a>
<?php }  ?>

<?php if(get_field('sales_leaflet')) ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('sales_leaflet'); ?>" class="leaflet-button" target=_"blank">Sales Leaflet</a>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: which button is displaying ?

Comment: All three are displaying, even if i don't enter a link in Wordpress, it just shows the button but without a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if(get_field('owners_manual') != "") ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('owners_manual'); ?>" class="pdf-button" target=_"blank">Owners Manual</a>
<?php }  ?>

<?php if(get_field('parts_booklet') != "") ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('parts_booklet'); ?>" class="parts-button" target=_"blank">Parts Booklet</a>
<?php }  ?>

<?php if(get_field('sales_leaflet') != "") ?>
<?php {  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('sales_leaflet'); ?>" class="leaflet-button" target=_"blank">Sales Leaflet</a>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: no luck, the buttons are still showing with an empty link.

Comment: the link to the file uploaded in Wordpress

Comment: Means that field is not empty and that field is set. That is why button is displaying

Comment: Sorry, the link only shows on the ones I filled out, the empty ones stick echo the button, but with no link.

Comment: For the empty one also, get_field('sales_leaflet') is displaying something ? Because if get_field('sales_leaflet') is not empty, then, only button should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

```
                        <!-- Owners Manual -->
                        <?php
                            if( get_field('owners_manual') ):
                            $owners_link = get_field('owners_manual');
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $owners_link ?>" class="pdf-button" target=_"blank">Owners Manual</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- Parts Booklet -->
                        <?php
                            if( get_field('parts_booklet') ):
                            $parts_link = get_field('parts_booklet');
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $parts_link ?>" class="parts-button" target=_"blank">Parts Booklet</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- Sales leaflet -->
                        <?php
                            if( get_field('sales_leaflet') ):
                            $sales_link = get_field('sales_leaflet');
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $sales_link ?>" class="leaflet-button" target=_"blank">Sales Leaflet</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```